# Convert 081020 to date format 08/10/20 without using any packages

Tags: r, date

I would like to convert column `c1` into date format without using any external packages.
E.g

```
C1         C2
081020     08/10/20
091020     09/10/20
101020     10/10/20
120219     12/02/19
```

Comment: Those are not `Date` objects, just strings that look like dates. If you intend to do anything "numeric" with them (sort, differencing, etc) then you need to convert to a proper `Date` object, with `as.Date(c("081020", "091020", "101020", "120219"), format = "%m%d%y")`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use  `base R` methods

```
df1$C2 <- format(as.Date(df1$C1, '%m%d%y'), '%m/%d/%y')
df1$C2
#[1] "08/10/20" "09/10/20" "10/10/20" "12/02/19"
```

---

If we want to `separate` into different columns

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df1 %>% 
     separate(C1, into = c('C1', 'C2', 'C3'), sep=c(2, 4))
```

---

Or using `base R`

```
read.csv(text = trimws(gsub("(..)", "\\1,", df1$C1), whitespace = ","),
       header = FALSE)
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(C1 = c("081020", "091020", "101020", "120219")), 
row.names = c(NA, 
-4L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: and how do i separate it into 3 different columns

Comment: @ArjunSarihyan you can try with `separate`.  updated the post

Comment: can you please give the example on the temporary dataset i gave.

Comment: @ArjunSarihyan it is your same data I copied, and create the structure with `dput`

Comment: @ArjunSarihyan i already updated with both `read.csv` and `separate`

Comment: i am getting an error while converting the string into the date format now, 
the error says character string is in a standard unambiguous format

Comment: @ArjunSarihyan can you show the `str(df1$C1)`?  Is it a numeric or `factor` column?

Comment: str(df..) gives the data in string format, 
081020, 091020, 101020, 120219

Comment: @ArjunSarihyan Do you have month, day, year or day, month, year in that order of occurence

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222748/discussion-between-arjun-sarihyan-and-akrun).